# Continuity and differentiability of a piecewise function

Tags: real-analysis

Let

$$  f(x) =
     \begin{cases}
       \phantom{-}3x^2 & : x \in \mathbb{Q^c}\\
       -5x^2 & : x \in \mathbb{Q}
     \end{cases}
    $$

Where is  $f(x)$ continuous? Is $f(x)$ differentiable anywhere?

Attempt:

I think $f(x)$ will be continuous at $0$ since $f(x)=-5(0)^2=0$ and I can always find a sequence of irrational numbers that will converge to $0$ so that $f(x)=3(0)^2=0$. However, I am not completely sure if this is the right approach to the question. Furthermore, I am unclear as to the differentiability of $f(x)$ at $0$.

Comment: What is the derivative of f(x) at 0? Can you take it?

Comment: The fact that you can find ONE sequence of irrational numbers converging to $0$ isn't enough; you need to know that EVERY sequence of irrational numbers converging to $0$ has a sequence of images under $f$ converging to $0$.  (But that's not hard to show.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right about $f$ being continuous at $x=0$, but your proof is wrong as noted by [Michael Hardy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11667/michael-hardy) in his [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525132/continuity-and-differentiability-of-a-piecewise-function#comment1123666_525132). Below I prove that $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ and hence continuous there.

It can be proved that $f$ isn't continuous at $x\neq 0$ because for any given $x\neq 0$ you can find a sequence of rational numbers that converges to $x$ and a sequence of irrational numbers that also convergers to $x$ and by taking limits you can see that they will differ.

As for differentiability it can only be differentiable at $x=0$, if at any point at all.

Let $h\in \Bbb R$.

We get $\dfrac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\begin{cases} 3h, &\text{ if }h\text{ is irrational}\\ -5h, &\text{ if }h \text{ is rational}\end{cases}$ and as $h\longrightarrow 0$ we get $0$, hence $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and $f'(0)=0$.